# Display values that are checked when editing in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, checkbox

I'm working on a laravel application. In this application I have three tables:

`subjects`

```
id | name
-- | ----
01 | maths
02 | english
```

`divisions`

```
id | name
-- | ----
01 | Senior High
02 | Junior High
```

`division_subject` **pivot table**

```
division_id | subject_id
--- | ---
01 | maths
02 | english
```

A subject can have many divisions, so, in my form I have a list of all divisions as checkboxes. I the subject is taught in a single division a single division will be checked. If the subject is taught is many divisons  all the divisions the subject is taught in will be checked also. Now this is working fine when inserting with no problems. This is how the form looks:
[image]

**Problem**

Now, I want to be able to edit a subject and when I click on a edit button I want all divisions that are checked to a subject checked or all divisions that are assigned to a subject in the **pivot table** checked.
This is what I haven't been able to get my head around in laravel. so far this is how my code looks:

Division controller that returns all the divisions to be assigned to a subject:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $divisions = Division::all();

        return $divisions->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
    }
    //return view('division.show', compact('divisions'));
}
```

This is how I'm rendering it in the table.

```
<td>
<!-- If a subject belongs to a division or divisions list all the divisions
that belongs to the subject -->
@if(count($subject->divisions))
    @foreach($subject->divisions as $division)

        <a href="#" data-type="checklist" data-value="{{$division->id}}" data-title="Select divisions" data-name="division" class="division" data-pk="{{$division->id}}" role="button">
            <span class="badge label-primary">{{$division->name}}</span>
        </a> 

    @endforeach
@endif
</td>
```

This i how I'm rendering it in a model that has a form.

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label for="division">Level</label>
    <p class="text-muted">Please select the division(s) the subject is taught within.</p>
    @foreach($divisions as $division)
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="division_id" name="division_id[]" value="{{$division->id}}"> {{$division->name}}
        </label>
    @endforeach                            
</div>
```

The thing is I'm doing the same in the edit form but don't know how to checked up that values that have been assigned to a subject.

Is there a way that when the user click the edit button than all the divisions assigned to the subject be checked up.

anchor element that shows edit modal.

```
<td>
    <a class="edit-modal" data-id="{{$subject->id}}" data-name="{{$subject->name}}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit" href="#" role="button">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit text-info"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

This is my script for now:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit-modal', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            /* Act on the event */
            $('#edit-name').val($(this).data('name'));
            $('#edit-modal').modal({
                show: true,
                backdrop:'static',
                keyboard:false
            });
        });
```

graphical view of my table:
[image]

Comment: from where you are getting data in Edit??

Comment: I think your problem is that you have getting when checkbox is checked..?

Comment: @DCoder I'm sorry I don't understand.

Comment: @MeeraTank thanks for the notice. I've just updated my post to show that. In my anchor element I have a attribute called `data-name` that's where I'm getting the data in edit. If that is what you're asking.

Comment: Yes this is what i was asking. here with name you also need array of division for making ckeckbox checked

Comment: using $('input[value="division_id"]').prop("checked", true); in each of that division you can make it work.

Comment: @MeeraTank I don't understand how you want me to make this work. I've added a picture to my post that shows how the divisions that are assigned to a subject are formatted.

Comment: you are having array for division like ['1'=> 'Elementary','2'=>'Nursey'] on click edit event you can set using  $.each( devision , function( key, value) {
          $('input[value= key]').prop("checked", true)
        });